# yolov4-darknet, how to show full loss/mAP graph if the training is several times

Tags: object-detection, yolov4

[chart_yolov4_custom, this is my trained loss/mAP graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poiab.png)

Why graph is showing only part I think is because I restart training in 2、3 times, so I think this is the last time I'vd trained.

My question is. Is there still a chance to plot whole 6000 steps loss/mAP graph?

Or I only can training without interruption?
Thank you guys and looking for your answer!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you trained the model several times. There is no solution except you train the model once again but without interruption.